# How to compare values of multiple columns with similar name patterns at once?

Tags: r, match, apply, sapply

I have a big dataframe, containing multiple dichotomous variables. the first 10 rows are like this:

```r
structure(list(subject_sp_id = c("SP0189536", "SP0287404", 
"SP0268021", "SP0313735", "SP0050394", "SP0173973", "SP0035655", 
"SP0360624", "SP0153386", "SP0229810"), sex = c("Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Female"),  attn1 = c(0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), adhd1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), conduct1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), intermitt_explos1 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), behav_odd1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), devid1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), dev1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L), lang_dis1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L), ld1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), motor1 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mutism1 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), soc_prag1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), dev_speech1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), eating_probs1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), eating_disorder1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), encopres1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), enures1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), feeding_dx1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
    mood_anx1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), mood_bipol1 = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mood_dep1 = c(0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mood_dmd1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mood_hoard1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mood_ocd1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mood_or_anx1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), mood_sep_anx1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mood_soc_anx1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), neuro_sz1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), pers_dis1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), schiz1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), tics1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), attn2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), adhd2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), conduct2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), intermitt_explos2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), behav_odd2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L), devid2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L), dev2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), lang_dis2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L), ld2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), 
    motor2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mutism2 = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), soc_prag2 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), dev_speech2 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), eating_probs2 = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), eating_disorder2 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), encopres2 = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), enures2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), feeding_dx2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mood_anx2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), mood_bipol2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mood_dep2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), mood_dmd2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mood_hoard2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mood_ocd2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), mood_or_anx2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), mood_sep_anx2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L), mood_soc_anx2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L), neuro_sz2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), pers_dis2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), schiz2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    tics2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), sex2 = c("Female", 
    "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
    "Male", "Male"), age_band = structure(c(8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 6L), .Label = c("0-3", "3-6", "6-9", 
    "9-12", "12-15", "15-18", "18-21", "21-31", "31+"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now I would like to calculate the concordance rate of each variable (Va, Vb, Vc) between two measuring points 1 and 2, with covariates of age and sex i.e., the percentage of matching/unmatching of each item.

After tried Roman's tidyverse answer, I got output like this:

```r
structure(list(gr1 = c("attn_2", "adhd2", "conduct2", 
"intermitt_explos2", "behav_odd2", "devid2", "lang_dis2", 
"dev", "ld2", "motor2", "mutism2", "soc_prag2", 
"dev_speech2", "eating_disorder2", "eating_probs2", "encopres2", 
"enures2", "feeding_dx2", "mood_anx2", "mood_bipol2"), `0-3` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `3-6` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `6-9` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `9-12` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `12-15` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `15-18` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `18-21` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `21-31` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `31+` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Do you have any idea why I got such output and how should I resolve it?

Comment: why Vc in 25-30 shows 0.5? Shouldn't it be 0?

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you can try a `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-1:-3, names_to = c("gr1", "gr2"), names_sep = 2) %>%
  group_by(ID, age, gr1) %>% 
  summarise(same=sum(length(unique(value))==1)) %>% 
  group_by(age, gr1) %>% 
  summarise(perc=sum(same)/n()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = age, values_from = perc, values_fn = unique)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  gr1   `18-25` `25-30` `30+`
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 Va        0.5     0.5     1
2 Vb        0       0.5     0
3 Vc        0.5     0       1
```

Simply change all "age" to "sex" for gender specific values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But since my variable names are so different, e.g., eating_disorder1,2, depression1, 2, dev_id1,2, etc. Would you suggest I change all the variables into Va, Vb, Vc and then change them back when reporting, or is there another way to directly do the above with original names?

Comment: I tried your method, it worked fine in theory. Yet the result only gave a concordance rate of 10 variables (I have 31), and the message of '`summarise()` regrouping output by 'family_sf_id', 'age_band' (override with `.groups` argument)
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'age_band' (override with `.groups` argument)'. Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: I changed the names_sep to 32 as that is the length of my longest variable name. It gives 31 variables, which is good. However, everything became 1, which is clearly not right. Could you please give me some suggestions?

Comment: you have to provide some of your data. include the output of `dput(head(data, 20)` for instance.

Comment: Hi Roman, I've edited my original question, does that make it any clearer?